# Can't bind when accumulating errors into a Nel<ApplicationError> using Arrow 1.2.0 parZipOrAccumulate

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I'm using the new `parZipOrAccumulate` function from Arrow 1.2.0-RC to parallelize two calls and accumulate their errors if any:

```
private suspend fun getUser(legalId: UserLegalId): Either<ApplicationError, User>
```

```
private suspend fun getDepartment(departmentCode: DepartmentCode): Either<ApplicationError, Department>
```

```
        override suspend fun execute(param: AddUserToDepartmentInfo): Either<Nel<ApplicationError>, Department> = either {
            val pair: Pair<User, Department> =
                parZipOrAccumulate<ApplicationError, User, Department, Pair<User, Department>>(
                    {e1: ApplicationError, e2 : ApplicationError-> nonEmptyListOf(e1,e2)},
                    { getUser(param.userLegalId).bind() },
                    { getDepartment(param.departmentCode).bind() }
                ) { a, b -> Pair(a, b) }
            saveUserDrivenPort.save(pair.first.copy(departmentId = param.departmentCode)).bind()
            pair.second
        }
```

None of the three `.bind()` calls in the code above compile because it expects the error types to match (`ApplicationError` <-> `Nel<ApplicationError>`).

How can I accumulate errors in a `Nel<ApplicationError>` when I need to bind functions that may fail with an `ApplicationError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [answered in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977728/how-can-we-use-context-receivers-and-arrow-1-2-0-parziporaccumulate-no-required) we can get rid of the combinator function and the errors will be automatically added to a Nel.

```
        override suspend fun execute(param: AddUserToDepartmentInfo): Either<Nel<ApplicationError>, Department> = either {
            val pair: Pair<User, Department> =
                parZipOrAccumulate(                   
                    { getUser(param.userLegalId).bind() },
                    { getDepartment(param.departmentCode).bind() }
                ) { a, b -> Pair(a, b) }
            saveUserDrivenPort.save(pair.first.copy(departmentId = param.departmentCode)).mapLeft { nonEmptyListOf(it) }.bind()
            pair.second
        }
```