# How can we use context receivers and Arrow 1.2.0 parZipOrAccumulate? No required context receiver found: Cxt

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

Given the following functions:

```
context(Raise<ApplicationError>)
suspend fun getUser(legalId: UserLegalId): User
```

```
context(Raise<ApplicationError>)
suspend fun getDepartment(departmentCode: DepartmentCode): Department
```

```
context(Raise<ApplicationError>)
suspend fun save(user: User): User
```

I want to invoke them in parallel and accumulate their errors:

```
        context(Raise<Nel<ApplicationError>>)
        override suspend fun execute(param: AddUserToDepartmentInfo): Department {
            val pair: Pair<User, Department> =
                parZipOrAccumulate(
                    {e1, e2 -> e1 + e2},
                    { getUser(param.userLegalId) },
                    { getDepartment(param.departmentCode) }
                ) { a, b -> Pair(a, b) }
            saveUserDrivenPort.save(pair.first.copy(departmentId = param.departmentCode))
            return pair.second
        }
```

However, the `getUser()` and `getDepartment()` invocations inside parZipOrAccumulate don't compile:

```
No required context receiver found: Cxt { context(arrow.core.raise.Raise<xxx.ApplicationError>) private open suspend fun getUser(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try omitting the `{e1, e2 -> e1 + e2}` argument? That is not needed in this case because the `Nel` accumulator is inferred by the outer `Nel<ApplicationError>`.

```kotlin
context(Raise<ApplicationError>)
suspend fun getUser(legalId: UserLegalId): User

context(Raise<ApplicationError>)
suspend fun getDepartment(departmentCode: DepartmentCode): Department  

context(Raise<ApplicationError>)
suspend fun save(user: User): User

context(Raise<Nel<ApplicationError>>)
suspend fun execute(param: AddUserToDepartmentInfo): Department {
  val pair: Pair<User, Department> =
    parZipOrAccumulate(
      { getUser(param.userLegalId) },
      { getDepartment(param.departmentCode) }
    ) { a, b -> Pair(a, b) }
    
  // Turn `Raise<ApplicationError>` into `Raise<Nel<ApplicationError>>`
  recover({
    saveUserDrivenPort.save(pair.first.copy(departmentId = param.departmentCode))
  }) { raise(nonEmptyListOf(it)) }

  return pair.second
}
```

I tried this locally, and it works for me. The `Raise<ApplicationError>` is exposed as `ScopedRaiseAccumulate<ApplicationError>` in the lambda of `parZipOrAccumulate`.

Comment: As you said, removing the error combinator fixed the problem form getUser() and getDepartment() but, saveUserDrivenPort.save() still gets the "No required contextReceiver found". Can you tell why?

Comment: That is very strange, this code compiles and runs fine for me. https://gist.github.com/nomisRev/729c2f9192fb7fd68b6bf5de3bd9e93a.

The editor might be confused since `parZipOrAccumulate` defines it `Raise<E>.() ->` and you expect `context(Raise<E>)` but it should compile fine. Maybe refreshing the window, or Gradle might fix a cache issue in the IDEA analyser.

Comment: I think your sample is missing this bit `saveUserDrivenPort.save()` before `return pair.second`. You can see the actual code here: https://github.com/codependent/hexapp/blob/context-receivers/src/main/kotlin/com/codependent/hexapp/application/port/in/impl/DepartmentUseCasesImpl.kt#L89

Comment: Yes, I omitted that on purpose in favour of `TODO()`. Is the code compiling for you?

I see that with `saveUserDrivenPort.save()` you're not calling `bind`. You can do that by using `getOrElse { raise(nonEmptyListOf(it)) }` or `mapLeft { nonEmptyListOf(it) }.bind()`.

Comment: `saveUserDrivenPort.save()` signature is `context(Raise<ApplicationError>)
suspend fun save(user: User): User` so I don't have an Either to `bind()`, ??

Comment: Should I use a function like fold/recover wrapping `saveUserDrivenPort.save()`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you _transform_ the error from `Raise` using `recover` similar to how you'd use `mapLeft`.

`recover({ saveUserDrivenPort.save(...) }) { raise(nonEmptyListOf(it)) }`. I updated the original example.